# Incredibly slow bash loop

Tags: bash, performance, function, while-loop

I did a quick thing to just stuff some commands into a function and loop over a file and run it for each line. I am amazed at the slow speed this achieves.

Any suggestions as to how can I speed up this loop which uses the smelly function?

```
#!/bin/bash
list="lists/test.txt"

smellyfunc() {

alphabet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
bgam=bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
plaintext=THXGAWDITSFRIDAYTODAY
plaintext=$(echo "$plaintext" | tr A-Z a-z | sed s/[^a-z]//g) 
step=0

while test -n "$plaintext"
do
  key=$1
  length=${#key}
  char=${plaintext:0:1}
  shift=${key:$step:1}
  code=$(echo -n $(($(expr index $bgam $char)-$(expr index $bgam $shift))))
  step=$(($(($step+1))%$length))
  if [[ $code -lt 0 ]]
    then
    code=$((code+26))
  fi
  if [[ $code -gt 25 ]]
    then
    code=$((code-26))
  fi
  echo -n ${alphabet:$code:1}
  plaintext=${plaintext:1}
done
}

while read line; do
   key="$line"
   result="$(smellyfunc "$key")"
   echo "$result" "$key"
done < $list
```

Thanks!

Comment: Rule #1 of writing bash with decent performance: Don't use command substitution (`$( )` or equivalents). Rule #2: Don't use pipelines. Rule #3: Don't use external commands.

Comment: ...that said, for CPU-bound code, a completely different implementation is typically appropriate (or just a different interpreter; David Korn ksh93 is far faster than bash once the necessarily-slow things like subshells &c have been removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we rewrite so that you don't need to call any external programs, and you save up echo-ing the output, we can get a big speedup:

```
# function to mimic `expr index`
index() {
    local prefix=${1%%$2*}
    local i=${#prefix}
    if [[ $prefix == $1 ]]; then
        # substring $2 not found in $1
        i=-1
    fi
    echo $((i+1))
}

aromaticfunc() {
    local alphabet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    local bgam=bcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
    local step=0
    local -l plaintext=THXGAWDITSFRIDAYTODAY
    plaintext=${plaintext//[^a-z]/}
    local key length char shift code
    local result=""

    while [[ -n $plaintext ]]; do
        key=$1
        length=${#key}
        char=${plaintext:0:1}
        plaintext=${plaintext:1}
        shift=${key:$step:1}
        code=$(( $(index $bgam $char) - $(index $bgam "$shift") ))
        code=$(( (code+26) % 26 ))
        step=$(( (step+1) % length ))
        result+=${alphabet:$code:1}
    done
    echo "$result"
}
```

then see if we get the same result:

```
$ s=$( smellyfunc helloworld )
$ a=$( aromaticfunc helloworld )
$ [[ $s == $a ]] && echo OK || echo different
OK
```

and, to address the question, is it faster?

```
$ time for i in {1..100}; do result=$(smellyfunc helloworld); done 

real    0m7.339s
user    0m5.739s
sys 0m0.967s
$ time for i in {1..100}; do result=$(aromaticfunc helloworld); done 

real    0m2.725s
user    0m1.879s
sys 0m0.613s
```

So, about a 3x speedup.

Comment: I'd bet that implementing it in a language like Perl would give an even bigger improvement

Comment: Change the `local`s to `typeset`s and you have support for ksh, which can run the same script much faster. That said, this is still forking -- more efficient to have `index` use indirect assignment to pass back results so its invocation doesn't need to use command substitution.

Comment: Using ksh93, I get 0.13s wall-clock time for the 100-invocation loop.

Comment: ...see https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/06bfd99275f9e6320e6554581854a2cd

Comment: I'm running a ubuntu vm in windows 10, so I'm already at a speed penalty. However, using ksh gives an even more dramatic improvement: smelly = 3.24s real, aromatic (after s/local/typeset/) = 0.20s real

Comment: bash is just a slow language. Lots of nice interactive goodies, and speed is not the prime concern for an interactive shell.

Comment: @Charles nice use of the nameref.

Comment: Agreed. When I want to select a fast, readable high-level language for implementing a CPU-bound algorithm, I tend to reach for [Julia](https://julialang.org/) -- not just faster than Perl/Python/whatnot, but [often faster than *C*](https://julialang.org/benchmarks/).